# Why my laravel vue crud is not posting data automatically to the posts section

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Hi friends i am using laravel 5.6 with vue.js for crud function . I want to get the posts which i just posted in posts section without reloading the whole page again. I have written this code but these codes are sending the data to the console but not to the posts view section .

My app.js looks like this

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    msg: 'Update new Post:',
    content:'', 
    posts:[]
    },

    ready:function(){
        this.created();
    },

    created(){
         axios.get('http://{mylink}/home/post')
             .then(response=>{
                 console.log(response.data);//show if success
                 this.posts = response.data; // putting posts into array

             })
             .catch(function (error) {
                 console.log(error.response);
             });

    },


    methods:{
        addPost(){

            axios.post('http://{mylink}/home/addPost', {
                content:this.content

            })
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('Data updated');
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    alert('Your post has been updated');
                    app.posts=reponse.data;
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error.response);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

my controllers looks like this

```
 public function posts(){
        $posts=DB::table('posts')
        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','posts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('profiles','profiles.user_id','posts.user_id')
        ->get();

        return view('home',compact('posts'));
    }
    public function addPost(Request $request){
        $content = $request->content;
        $createPost=DB::table('posts')
        ->insert(['content'=>$content,'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
        'status'=>0,'created_at'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),'updated_at'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")]);

        if($createPost){
            $posts_json = DB::table('posts')
         ->leftJoin('users','users.id','posts.user_id')
         ->leftJoin('profiles','profiles.user_id','posts.user_id')
         ->orderBy('posts.created_at','DESC')->take(2)
         ->get();

        return $posts_json;
        }
    }
```

Routes looks like this

```
Route::post('/home/addPost','PostController@addPost')->name('home.addPost');
Route::get('/home/post',function(){
    $posts_json = DB::table('posts')
        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','posts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('profiles','profiles.user_id','posts.user_id')
         ->orderBy('posts.created_at','DESC')
        ->get();

        return $posts_json;
});
```

and my view looks like this

```
 <div v-for="post in posts">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                                <p>@{{post.content}}</p>
                             <footer class="blockquote-footer">Status By <cite title="Source Title">@{{post.name}}</cite>  <img src="{{url('/')}}/img/" alt="Card image cap" height="30px" width="30px" style="border-radius:50%;"></footer>
                            </blockquote>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Remove the ready function.The created will executed itself

Comment: Also i think it is incorrect the {mylink} in : axios.get('http://{mylink}/home/post')

Comment: You can use either created() or mounted() life cycle hooks of VueJS. You do not need to use ready function for your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

As noted in your comments above, this is an issue with authorization. I'll leave my old answer here for posterity, but including the status code from the start of the question would be good next time.

---

I believe your 'this' context is invalid when used inside the callback like that. Try something like this (edit) just realized you wanted the addPosts section:

```
    addPost(){
        let vm = this;
        axios.post('http://{mylink}/home/addPost', {
            content:this.content
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log('Data updated');
            if (response.status == 200) {
                alert('Your post has been updated');
                vm.posts=reponse.data;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error.response);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Not working sir. The data is updating in console but not in post view

Comment: When you use arrow functions there are not problem with this.So woulb be better to use arrow functions instead of putting the this into a variable

Comment: same issue sustained

Answer (score -1):

> I see many problems to your code but if  the problem is only in addPost (you said that there is the problem) method then replace it with the follow:

```
    addPost(){

        axios.post('http://{mylink}/home/addPost', {
            content:this.content

        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            if (response.status == 200) {
                alert('Your post has been updated');
                this.posts = reponse.data;
            }
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error.response);
        });

    }
```

*also if you replace your method with the method that i posted you will be able to see what response you get from backend since i console logged it.Then you will see if you get a desired response*

Comment: data being updated in console the very soon i click the post button but in console it showing un-defined and neither it is updating in view

Comment: So you get undefined when you console the response?

Comment: Yes sir. Its showing undefined but getting the data when i am relodig the page

Comment: So i think the issue is the {mylink}.Remove it and try to use the backend url as it is

Comment: nah not working .. i am adding a screen shot kindly check it

Comment: So it says forbidden.Are you using authentication?

Comment: So you have to send the token with the request

Comment: are you using interceptors?

Comment: nah i am not i guess

Comment: So when the user is authenticated you have to include Authorization header.

Comment: yes i do . use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; using this one

Comment: In axios.You have to put Headers.

Comment: how to do so ? can you give me an example or link

Comment: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`; In that way you include the headers in every request.But you have to get the token

Comment: cant i use jquery ajax instead of this ?

Comment: Axios is awesome.But you have to get some tutorials about vue and axios.

Comment: Okey boss . Thanks . I ll get those tutorials first